# Virtualy Test WPF Compatibility

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, testing, virtualization, performance-testing

I am running Windows 8.1 on a Intel core i7/8GB hardware configuration.
I had developed one WPF application which is running absolutely fine on my machine, but my some of clients have different low end configured devices like Intel ATOM dual core/2 GB on which the application is lagging.

My question is how do I create a virtual environment like my client's and test the application on it.

Does anyone know how to achieve this without or with a VM?  Are there any features in Visual Studio to support this type of testing?

Comment: This begs the question what test strategy you have in place for your product?  Have you analysed what types of devices you would like to support?  Do you have a supported devices/OS list?  Although testing on one other configuration that your developer setup is good you probably need to do a lot more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Using VM is OK. there are no any tools in VS to solve it.

Just create VM with 1 GB of RAM and 1 CPU

Comment: just for curiosity ,whats is AppVerifier is for in windows ?